# How should gitflow hotfixes work?

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-flow, hotfix

We use Gitflow for our web builds, and I have a question about how `hotfixes` are supposed to work. But first I should explain that we don't *quite* use the normal Gitflow workflow.

I understand that usually you would branch your `features`, they would merge into `develop` when finished, you would create your `release`, `release` gets merged into `master` and you deploy that, as an actual "versioned release".

However, as this is client work, we don't do "releases", instead features are deployed as and when they are required, so changes from our `feature` branches are merged into `master` on an ad-hoc basis.

This did cause problems as the `feature` branches were branched from `develop` which was way ahead of `master`; merging these `feature` branches into `master` would merge other changes into `master` (changes that were present in `develop` at the time the `feature` was branched that weren't yet in `master`). We were aware that this is not how Gitflow is designed, but we needed a branching model of some sort, so we (sort of) solved this by cherrypicking commits instead of merging branches.

So, I understand these issues, and I don't believe they're contributing to the issue I have now, but just in case, this is how we use it. However my question is:

**How are `hotfixes` *supposed* to merge in?**

In my head, the scenario is:

- `master` is "production"
- `develop` is ahead of `master`

You then want to patch an immediate issue with a `hotfix` branch. In Gitflow, this branches from `master`, and when you finish the `hotfix`, this gets merged into `master` **and** `develop`

But how does this not cause massive problems?

Recently, I tried to create a `hotfix` to change a single line of copy in one file. I finished the `hotfix`, and the change merged into `master` with no problems, but when it tired to merge into `develop`, it created an enormous 35 file diff with several merge conflicts in files I hadn't touched, due to the disparity between `develop` and `master`.

I understand that this is because you are merging the `hotfix` *branch*, which was itself branched from `master`, into `develop`, not specifically the *change* or single *commit*, so I understand *why* there was the massive merge commit/conflict.

However, what I *don't* understand is, with this in mind, how `hotfixes` work at all "in the real world", considering they are branched from `master` and then merged into `develop`, which is, by design, way ahead of `master`. This is why I don't think the way we're using Gitflow is the issue, because `develop` would be ahead of `master` regardless of our non-standard deployment process - I can't see why this doesn't cause huge headaches regardless of the project or exact workflow.

What doesn't seem to make sense to me is that your `hotfix` could be something as simple as changing a `true` to a `false` or changing an email address, whatever, but to get it into `master`, you may have to wrestle with an enormous set of merge conflicts. Is this just standard behaviour? Is this just how `hotfixes` work, and if you have to sit and sort out a massive merge conflict, then so be it? Would it not be easier to just cheerypick a commit? It just seems like there is such massive scope to introduce an error for what could be such a tiny change - you're dealing with two branches that are, perhaps, several months and hundreds of commits away from each other.

I may just be misunderstanding the process of `hotfixes`, but if I am, I'm not sure which bit.

Comment: Consider the repository commit tree in Gitflow: if you are branching off of `master` (e.g. `myHotfix1`), make commit(s), and merge back into `master`, that merge is able to resolve as a fast-forward. Therefore, encountering a merge conflict is _impossible_ unless someone merged something else in the meantime. A major point of Gitflow is that merge conflicts are resolved in topic branches so that pull requests into public branches (`develop`, `release_x`, etc.) are able to be fast-forwarded. The trick is to keep all the private/topic branches updated with their respective base.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do the following?
 1) Branch hotfix from master
 2) Merge hotfix into master
 3) Rebase develop onto master

Answer (score 3):

For first picture in [this link](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

[image]

I don't see why there would be many conflicts. The changes which are merged to `develop` are only the latest hotfix, of maybe previous hotfixes, if they were not merged for some reason in their turn.

(though I would rather merge the `hotfix` into `master`, and them merged `master` to `develop`, instead of directly merging `hotfix` to `develop`, just to avoid criss-cross merges, but it should not change much)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will see the same conflicts if you merge your *master* into *develop*, even without a hotfix.

So the hotfix itself isn't the problem. The real question is, why does merging your master into develop generate so many conflicts? The answer is that gitflow was not followed correctly, otherwise every commit in master would have been merged into develop already. When done right, the hotfix merge works the way you expect: only the change in the hotfix should be new.

The following should fix it. Do a fresh merge of master to develop without immediately committing. You will see the conflicts. Resolve them all in favor of the develop branch (e.g. reset and remove all changes.) Then commit the merge. This "empty merge" should tell git that develop has everything that's in master. Future hotfixes should then work better.

I ran into this same issue recently. I don't know how our history got confused (or yours). Maybe a developer committed a change directly into master and never merged it back. Or maybe they had problems and tried using separate commits instead of merging a change from one to the other. It's likely to happen again so maybe next time I'll figure out who or what is the culprit.